# Concatenation when creating a file name

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to check if a file exists in a specific folder on the local machine. The file name is created by concatenation of the first and last names. I am not sure how to pass the file name into the file.exists since the file name changes each time? I am using the following statement to check the folder.

Code:

```
if(File.Exists(@"C:\TestDocuments\filename.xml"))
{
  MessageBox.Show("The File Already Exists");
}
```

Comment: `Path.Combine(String, String)`?

Comment: try google here is a good starting point [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Dai - Having read about that, it does not check if the file is there. Thanks for the down vote and not answering the question.

Comment: @KevinSchultz - He answered your question and you don't know that he down voted you.  You can use `Path.Combine` inside of `File.Exists`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path.Combine(String, String) concatenate the two strings, with an intervening separator character. I think here you need is string.format may be like

```
 if(File.Exists(string.Format(@"C:\TestDocuments\{0}{1}.xml",firstName,lastName))
```

Comment: `Path.Combine` will automatically add the `\` between two strings.  `String.Format` would require you to manually add the `\` otherwise it won't properly form a path to the file.

Comment: @Greg-  If you want to combine path(different level of directory) then you can use Path.Combine but here the user want to combine filename(without separator character).

Answer (score 0):

Kevin, as @Dai said you will want to use `Path.Combine`.

Your code afterwards might look something like this:

```
if(File.Exists(Path.Combine(directoryPath, filePath)))
{
      MessageBox.Show("The File Already Exists");
}
```

This will combine a say "C:\TestDocuments" with "filename.xml" and can be used for other file names too.

Answer (score 0):

You could essentially do something like this:

```
public static string CheckFileName(string name)
{
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
          throw new ArgumentNullException();

     int i = 0;

     string file = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"FolderPath"], name);
     while(File.Exist(file))
           file = String.Format(file-{0}, i++);

     return file;
}
```

That is an incredibly rough implementation, as it doesn't handle file extensions and or null values.  But if the file exist it should auto increment until a file name that is free exist.  This will alleviate files being overridden, but it all depends on your goal.

The above **Does**:

- Pulls the path from your `app.config`, which would allow you to encrypt it.
- Auto increments
- Validates that the parameter isn't `null`.
- Since it is a method, it is reusable.

The above **Doesn't**

- Handle extensions in the file name.
- Remove previous file, there isn't any overwriting.

---

When dealing with file paths, you often need `Path.Combine` to avoid any errors in slashes.  That is where `String.Format` can run into issues, unless a separator exist.  The Microsoft Developer Network has some great information on this.

You should check `System.IO`.